# Check if index is inside 2d list [Python]

Tags: python, list, indexing, 2d

I have to write a function (def) that checks if index that I write is inside the  2d list. If it is it must return True, otherwise it must return False.

```
def height(board):
    height=0
    for x in board:
        height+=1
    return height

def width(board):
    wid=len(board[0])
    return wid

def on_board(board, x, y):
    check=False
    x1 = int(x)
    y1 = int(y)
    for x,y in board:
        if x1 > height(board) or y1 > width(board):
            check=False
    else:
        check=True
    return check
```

List looks something like this:

```
board = [["V1", "V1"],
         ["V2", "V2"],
         ["V3", "V3"]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is with `try..except..else`, which will attempt to access that spot on the board. If it works, it's a valid location, and the `else` block will be entered. If not, it isn't, and the `except` block will be entered. As a bonus, you can also check for whether `x` and `y` are valid integers. Any failure here will produce `False`.

```
def on_board(board, x, y):
    try:
        board[int(x)][int(y)]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Also, the height of the board is simply `def height(board): return len(board)`. But if you only have `height()` and `width()` for the purpose of `on_board()`, then you don't need `height()` and `width()` at all.

As [determined in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96985/discussion-between-dimitrije-mitic-and-tigerhawkt3), the testing suite which is checking your program is using 0-indexed rows and columns like we are, but the first value is the column (like an x-coordinate on a graph) and the second value is the row. It also doesn't accept indices of `-1` for the user to indicate the last row/column. Finally, it's testing the function with integers already, so there's no need to cast with `int()`.

```
def on_board(board, x, y):
    return x in range(len(board[0])) and y in range(len(board))
```

This checks whether `x` is between `0` (inclusive) and the number of columns in a row (non-inclusive), and whether `y` is between `0` (inclusive) and the number of rows in the board (non-inclusive). It then returns the boolean value for whether both of those conditions are true.

Comment: As a suggestion, the OP could create a `Board` class and encapsulate some of these details in there.

Comment: I get this error:
board[int(x)][int(y)]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I had to edit: except ValueError, IndexError to: except ValueError as IndexError. Because: "Python version 3.4 does not support this syntax."

Comment: elf.assertTrue(on_board(board, 1, 2))
AssertionError: False is not true
Still, i get this error..

Comment: Well yeah. From your question's text: "checks if index that I write is inside the 2d list". An index of `[1][2]` is not inside the board. Does your testing suite use a 1-indexed board?

Comment: The testing suite is using the exact same board as I wrote in my question.

Comment: Yes, but is it assuming user inputs that are 1-indexed? Meaning, would the first row be row 0 or row 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96985/discussion-between-dimitrije-mitic-and-tigerhawkt3).

Answer (score 1):

You can use your two methods as written, then your `on_board` method can be simply checking those

```
def height(board):
    return len(board)

def width(board):
    return len(board[0])

def on_board(board, x, y):
    return x < width(board) and y < height(board)
```

For example

```
>>> board = [["V1", "V1"],
             ["V2", "V2"],
             ["V3", "V3"]]
>>> on_board(board, 1, 0)
True
>>> on_board(board, 3, 4)
False
```

Comment: I get this error:
AssertionError: True is not false